# iOS screen rotation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, landscape-portrait

I have a program that has multiple ViewControllers.

In some I need **only** portrait mode but on others I need only **landscape** mode.

When I come from a portrait viewController the system should automatically put the new viewController in landscape.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

this may help

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html

Comment: I use - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation and - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation but none of this is fired? I can not find reasion why.